# Reshaping a Dataframe with repeating column names

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, reshape, melt

I have data that looks like this:

```
    dataframe_1:                
    week    SITE        LAL SITE     LAL
0   1   BARTON CHAPEL   1.1 PENASCAL I  1
1   2   BARTON CHAPEL   1.1 PENASCAL I  1
2   3   BARTON CHAPEL   1.1 PENASCAL I  1
```

And, i need the final dataframe to look like this:

```
    dataframe_2:        
    week    SITE    LAL
0   1   BARTON CHAPEL   1.1
1   2   BARTON CHAPEL   1.1
2   3   BARTON CHAPEL   1.1
3   1   PENASCAL I  1
4   2   PENASCAL I  1
5   3   PENASCAL I  1
```

I've tried using 'melt' but I cannot get the desire result. Perhaps I'm using the wrong approach?
thank you,

Comment: How did you arrive to `dataframe_1`? Seems there's probably a better way to approach it so that you don't have to "melt" it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not a very generalizable solution, but will work on your example:

```py
df.groupby('week').apply( lambda _df : pd.concat((_df.iloc[:,1:3], _df.iloc[:,3:5]))).reset_index('week')
```

it groups by week and then reshapes with column selection + concatenation. Removing a superfluous index column in the end.

Answer (score 3):

If you had unambiguous column names:

```
   week           SITE  LAL      SITE.1  LAL.1
0     1  BARTON CHAPEL  1.1  PENASCAL I      1
1     2  BARTON CHAPEL  1.1  PENASCAL I      1
2     3  BARTON CHAPEL  1.1  PENASCAL I      1
```

You could use [`pandas.lreshape`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/dev/reference/api/pandas.lreshape.html):

```
pd.lreshape(df, {'SITE': ['SITE', 'SITE.1'], 'LAL': ['LAL', 'LAL.1']})
```

Output:

```
   week           SITE  LAL
0     1  BARTON CHAPEL  1.1
1     2  BARTON CHAPEL  1.1
2     3  BARTON CHAPEL  1.1
3     1     PENASCAL I  1.0
4     2     PENASCAL I  1.0
5     3     PENASCAL I  1.0
```

With your duplicated columns, you can [`melt`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.melt.html#pandas.DataFrame.melt) + [`pivot`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html):

```
out = (df
   .melt('week').assign(idx=lambda d: d.groupby(['week', 'variable']).cumcount())
   .pivot(index=['idx', 'week'], columns='variable', values='value')
   .reset_index('week').rename_axis(index=None, columns=None)
)
```

Output:

```
   week  LAL           SITE
0     1  1.1  BARTON CHAPEL
0     2  1.1  BARTON CHAPEL
0     3  1.1  BARTON CHAPEL
1     1    1     PENASCAL I
1     2    1     PENASCAL I
1     3    1     PENASCAL I
```

Comment: Hi, mozway, do you have any idea why `df.groupby(level=0, axis=1).agg(list)` throws error?

Comment: @Ynjxsjmh you need to use `.agg(lambda x: x.to_numpy().tolist())`. Else this applies `list` on the column names (try `.agg(''.join)`) ;)

Comment: @Ynjxsjmh your above question has now been asked (and answered) [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76809952/16343464) ;)

Comment: @Ynjxsjmh I have to say I struggled a bit to find your comment (the nickname didn't help :p)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by extracting from the dataframe_1 the columns you want to extract and concatenate at the bottom:

```
# create a dummy dataframe with 6 columns and 10 rows
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,100,size=(10, 6)), columns=list('ABCDEF'))

df_tempo = df[['D','E','F']]
```

Then renaming the columns of the temporary dataframe with the same name in your case ['week', 'SITE', 'LAL']:

```
df_tempo.columns = ['A','B','C']
```

And then concatenate the temporary with the subset of the first dataframe you want to keep:

```
df = pd.concat([df[['A','B','C']], df_tempo], axis=0, ignore_index=True)
```

Hope it helps!